# Does iOS SDK 5.0 (beta) support 3.1 devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

Is the iOS SDK 5.0 (beta 6) supposed to support running apps on 3.1.2 devices? My app compiles and runs correctly on a 4.3 iPad but when I set Deployment Target as 3.1 and try to compile/run the app on my 3.1.2 iPhone, I get an Uncategorized Internal Error:

```
Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE in         /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport- 915/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/XCCodeSignContext.m:1237
Details:  Error: failed to locate ResourceRules.plist in '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/ResourceRules.plist ' or '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ResourceRules.plist'
Object:   <XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext>
Method:   +defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x201f36fe0>{name = (null), num = 26}
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000011c3dac1c -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
  1  0x000000010006a1c4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000011c4b2d7a +[XCCodeSignContext defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x000000011c42b178 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x000000011c4bafb2 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000011c3ca4dd -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000011c3dbc9e -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff827db96c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff827db83d -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
  9  0x000000011c3db061 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x00007fff827db96c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 11  0x00007fff827db83d -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x000000011c424436 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x000000011c424840 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x00007fff83512204 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 15  0x00007fff808fefd6 _pthread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff808fee89 thread_start (in libSystem.B.dylib)

(null)
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff828067b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff82afcf03 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8285e969 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010006a1c4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 110
4   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c4b2d7a +[XCCodeSignContext defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:] + 2120
5   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c42b178 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] + 656
6   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c4bafb2 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] + 3744
7   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c3ca4dd -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] + 4889
8   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c3dbc9e -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] + 460
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff827db96c __invoking___ + 140
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff827db83d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 141
11  DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c3db061 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] + 594
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff827db96c __invoking___ + 140
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff827db83d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 141
14  DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c424436 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] + 388
15  DevToolsCore                        0x000000011c424840 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 510
16  Foundation                          0x00007fff83512204 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
17  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff808fefd6 _pthread_start + 331
18  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff808fee89 thread_start + 13
```

Comment: I don't think the question is. Some answers might... :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create Ad Hoc distribution for your app and then combination SDK 5 beta 6 and iPhone 3G can work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with provisioning.

Comment: Just guessing Mayoneez is using machine with armv6 instructions set which looks like is not supported with SDK 5. At least I have not found it yet.

Comment: @vanya: you are correct. My 3.1.2 iPhone a  first gen iPhone. I guess we need to wait for the final release to be sure whether it's supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Architextures" setting for both your Project and for the app's Target and make sure you have a line for all of the following:

```
armv6
armv7
i386
```

You have to specify these explicitly. The default "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" does not include armv6.

Comment: I had arm6 there as well so that wasn't the reason but thanks for the reminder.